# Indentation in Haskell - if statement

Tags: haskell

As an exercise in learning Haskell, I decided to try and translate some of my homeworks written in C using the GSL library. I am stumbling on many things, as the absolute beginner that I am.

I am not sure if the following is an indentation error or if I am not using the if statement correctly, and Google was no help. My goal is to code the cumulative distribution function of a normal distribution. ( see the edit for a leaner version )

Here is the code :

```
import Bindings.Gsl.MathematicalFunctions

cdf_normal_as :: x -> fx (Double, Double)

let {   
    fx = 0;
    psi_x = 0;
    y  = 0;
    b  = 0.2316419;
    a1 = 0.319381530;
    a2 = (-0.356563782);
    a3 = 1.781477937;
    a4 = (-1.821255978);
    a5 = 1.330274429;
    }

if x >= 0
    then 
    let
        y = 1 / ( 1 + b * x );
        psi_x = ( 1 / ( sqrt( 2 * M_PI) ) ) * exp ( -(pow(x,2) / 2 ));
    in
    fx = 1.0 - psi_x * ( a1 * y + a2 * y * y + a3 * y * y * y + a4 * y * y * y * y + a5 * y * y * y * y * y );

    else 
    let
        x = x * (-1);
        y = 1 / ( 1 + (b * x));
        psi_x = (1 / (sqrt(2 * M_PI) ) ) * exp( -(pow(x,2)/2 ) );   
    in
    fx = 1 - psi_x * (a1*y + a2*pow(y,2) + a3*pow(y,3) + a4*pow(y,4) + a5*pow(y,5));

    cdf_normal_as fx;
```

And here is the message I am getting :

```
Prelude> :l Normal_CDF.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Normal_CDF.hs, interpreted )

Normal_CDF.hs:20:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

What am I doing wrong?

--------------------------------------- EDIT

I did a leaner version to get a better feeling of what may be the problem. **My question is** : what is the proper and best way to do the equivalent of an if-else statement in Haskell?

The following code is supposed to take in the y variable, to set some variable x to a constant, and then to check if y is greater or lesser than 0 before doing a specific task if it is or isn't. This compiles.

```
plus_or_double :: Double -> Double

plus_or_double y = let {
            x = 2;
            } in case ( y>= 0 ) of
                True -> ( x + y )
                False -> y
```

I've used the case statement because I was unable to make the if statement works, although there must be a better way...

Comment: Either I'm wrong and you're using some very arcane syntax; Or this isn't even remotely haskell syntax (at best you could maybe pipe this into ghci with the multiline option being set). The question isn't so much what's wrong here; Rather there's very few things _right_ with this. You might wanna look into a beginner introduction again and build this starting with much smaller, working code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example that works. I think you need something to the left of `let { ...` :

```
module Main where {

test :: Double -> Double;
test x = let {

  first = let {
    a = x;
    b = a + x*x;
  } in a+b; 

  second = x*x*x;

} in first + second;


main = do
  print $ test 5

}
```

See [Haskell Wikibook : Explicit characters in place of indentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#Explicit_characters_in_place_of_indentation)